# How to completely stop pipeline in python-social-auth without throwing errors?

Tags: django, pipeline, python-social-auth

I need to customize pipeline for registration through the social networks.
In case if user doesn't provide email, I want to revoke token and after that redirect user to specific page. I know, that there is `SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_ERROR_URL` option in `settings.py`, but I don't want to throw error and redirect him to common error page.

---

So, can I completely stop pipeline (I mean not only suspend for further usage, but break, destroy, kill, finish ahead of time) and redirect user to specific page without throwing error?